# JSPM multiple bundles

Tags: bundling-and-minification, jspm

I'm hoping that someone can provide som help or hints for a scenario I have.

I am trying to setup jspm with the following structure:

Appbundle: My own javascripts for my angular app, vill be minified as part of my buildprocess.

Pluginbundle: A bunch of preminified 3rd party libraries that are already minified but need to be concatenated (this would be small standalone 3rd files like a datepicker and select2).

Use globals for larger libraries like angular, moment and jquery so they can be loaded from CDNs.

I've been trying to understand how this is handled in jspm but I can't seem to find any real examples, just.commemts along the line of "just shim them" and "exclude them from sfx".
I've tried both those things, but no matter what I do it seems that jspm bundles all the dependencies in my appbundle.js file which makes it far too big.

Is there anyone that has experience in setting something like this up? Is it even possible in jspm, or will it fight against effiency to make rhings simpler?

Grateful for any hints you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could found is to update JSPM to the latest 0.17-beta.

This allow you to use some arguments for the static builder, like `--global-deps` and `--externals` which describe dependencies to be excluded form the bundle.

I then load the bundle as a script tag, as well as those external dependencies.

See the guide for [JSPM 0.17-beta](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/static-builds-with-rollup-optimization.html).